# How to fuse (kind of merge) some items in a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I have created the following three types in Haskell:

```
type Product = (Int, String, Float)

type Order = (Product, Int)

type Purchase = [Order]
```

The idea is that every `Product` has an ID (`Int`), a name (`String`) and a price (`Float`). An `Order` is a certain discrete quantity (`Int`) of a given `Product`. And a `Purchase` is a list of `Order`s.

With that, I have to create a function that takes two `Purchase`s and then fuses them, returning another `Purchase` in return. For example, if an input is `[(product1, 2), (product1, 3), (product2, 4), (product2, 5), (product3, 10)]`, then the output should be `[(product1, 5), (product2, 9), (product3, 10)]`. In other words, it removes all repeated `Order`s, sums all quantities, and outputs the resultant "fused" `Purchase`.

Here it is the function I currently have. It doesn't work, and Haskell points out several `Couldn't match type` errors.

```
fusePurchases :: Purchase -> Purchase -> Purchase
fusePurchases p1 p2 = let productsIds = nub [productId | (aproduct, _) <- p1 ++ p2, let productId = fst aproduct] in [(aproduct, sum [snd p | p <- p1 ++ p2, fst (fst p) == productId])
      | productId <- productsIds, let aproduct = head [prod | prod <- map fst (p1 ++ p2), fst prod == productId]]
```

What is wrong with it? What changes should be made? What would be an operating function?

Thanks!

I tried to create a single function and use list comprehension to merge the products into a list with unique elements in which the sum of all quantities of every `Order` is summed according to the other `Order`s with the same `Product`.

Comment: A list isn't really the right data structure for this kind of operation. If you put it into a map instead, you can just have `fusionPurchases = unionWith (+)`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you haven't actually created *any* new types - you've just given an alias to 3 particular types. That's not necessarily wrong, but it's important to understand the difference between an actual type definition (with the `data` or `newtype` keyword) and a type alias (which uses the `type` keyword, as you have done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error:

```
MergeOrders.hs:10:107-114: error:
    • Couldn't match type: (Int, String, Float)
                     with: (a1, b1)
      Expected: (a1, b1)
        Actual: Product
    • In the first argument of ‘fst’, namely ‘aproduct’
      In the expression: fst aproduct
      In an equation for ‘productId’: productId = fst aproduct
    • Relevant bindings include
        productId :: a1 (bound at MergeOrders.hs:10:91)
   |
10 | fusionPurchases p1 p2 = let productsIds = nub [productId | (aproduct, _) <- p1 ++ p2, let productId = fst aproduct] in [(aproduct, sum [snd p | p <- p1 ++ p2, fst (fst p) == productId])
   |                                                                                                           ^^^^^^^^
```

arises because `aProduct` has type `Product`, which is a triple `(Int, String, Float)`, but you have tried to apply the function `fst` to it, and `fst` is only applicable to pairs.  In Haskell, applying `fst` to a pair works:

```
> fst (1,2)
1
```

but applying it to a triple does not:

```
> fst (1,2,3)

<interactive>:1:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type: (a, b0)
                  with actual type: (a0, b1, c0)
    • In the first argument of ‘fst’, namely ‘(1, 2, 3)’
      In the expression: fst (1, 2, 3)
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = fst (1, 2, 3)
    • Relevant bindings include it :: a (bound at <interactive>:1:1)
```

The other two errors result from similar problems.  In each case, you are trying to apply `fst` to a `Product` triple.

You may find it helpful to define `fst3`:

```
fst3 :: (a, b, c) -> a
fst3 (a, _, _) = a
```

With that definition, the following type checks okay:

```
fusionPurchases :: Purchase -> Purchase -> Purchase
fusionPurchases p1 p2 
  = let productsIds = nub [ productId | (aproduct, _) <- p1 ++ p2
                          , let productId = fst3 aproduct] 
    in [ (aproduct, sum [snd p | p <- p1 ++ p2, fst3 (fst p) == productId])
       | productId <- productsIds
       , let aproduct = head [ prod | prod <- map fst (p1 ++ p2)
                             , fst3 prod == productId]]
```